# Linkage Mechanism Doubt

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics, machine-design, acceleration, linkage

[image]

I am unsure how I would solve this. I have tried to solve it and got -29.1 but my attempt was wrong.
Could someone please lead me in the right direction or show me the way to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Show your working, then people can give you information on what you missed.

Comment: Definitely not -29.1. just take tangential acceleration and divide by the radius?

Answer (score 0):

Abel is correct.
Consider Point A on link OA.  It's simply the acceleration of point A in the y direction (tangential) divided by the distance OA.